# How do I empty a list pointed to by a parameter without freeing memory allocated to the list?

Tags: c, list, memory, free

In this code I'm trying to development a C module that implements a list collection that is similar to a Python list or a Java ArrayList.

It has a struct intlist_t:

```
typedef struct {
int *elems;   // Pointer to backing array.
int capacity; // Maximum number of elements in the list.
int size;     // Current number of elements in the list.
} intlist_t;
```

This is the code that I have created:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>`

#include "array_list.h"

/* Construct a new, empty list, and return a pointer to it
 * Parameter capacity is the # of elements that can be stored in the list.
 * Terminate the program via assert if capacity is <= 0.
 * Terminate the program via assert if memory for the list cannot be 
 * allocated from the heap.
 */ 

intlist_t *intlist_construct(int capacity)
{
    int *pa;
    pa = malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    assert(pa != NULL);

    intlist_t *list = malloc(sizeof(intlist_t));
    assert(list != NULL);

    list->capacity = capacity;
    list->size = 0;
    list->elems = pa;

    return list;
}

/* Destroy the list pointed to by parameter list, deallocating all memory 
* that was allocated from the heap.
* Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
*/

void intlist_destroy(intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    free(list->elems); /* Return the array to the heap. */
    free(list); /* Return the structure to the heap. */
}

/* Print the list pointed to by parameter list to the console.
* Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
*/

void intlist_print(const intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);

    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        printf("[]\n");
    }

    printf("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        if (i != list->size - 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", list->elems[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d]", list->elems[i]);
        }
    }
}

/* Insert element at the end of the list pointed to by list.
* Return true if element is appended; otherwise return false
* (which indicates that the list is full.)
* Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
*/

_Bool intlist_append(intlist_t *list, int element)
{
    assert(list != NULL);

    if (list->size < list->capacity)
    {
        list->elems[list->size] = element;
        list->size++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/* Return the maximum number of integers that can be stored in the list 
* pointed to by parameter list.
* Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
*/

int intlist_capacity(const intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    return list->capacity;
}

/* Return the number of integers in the list pointed to by parameter list.
* Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
*/
int intlist_size(const intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    return list->size;
}

/* Return the element located at the specified index, in the list
 * pointed to by parameter list. 
 * Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL, 
 * or if index is not in the range 0 .. intlist_size() - 1.
 */

int intlist_get(const intlist_t *list, int index)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    return list->elems[index];
}

/* Store element at the specified index, in the list pointed to by 
 * parameter list. Return the integer that was previously 
 * stored at that index.
 * Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL, 
 * or if index is not in the range 0 .. intlist_size() - 1.
 */
int intlist_set(intlist_t *list, int index, int element)
{
    assert(list != NULL);

    int previous;
    previous = list->elems[index];
    list->elems[index] = element;

    return previous;
}
```

The beginning part of my code works, however I'm having trouble with the following. I want to return a list that contains 0 integers when intlist_removal is returned. When I free the list, it doesn't work correctly.

```
 /* Empty the list pointed to by parameter list.
 * Memory allocated to the list is not freed, so the emptied list can 
 * continue to be used.
 * Terminate the program via assert if list is NULL.
 */

void intlist_removeall(intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    free(list);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more why it does not work correctly?

Comment: when i input: list=intlist_construct(10); so the capacity is 10 and initialize the list to [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] for example, once I call intlist_removeall(list), I get a size of 5 when instead the result should be 0 meaning it did not free the memory

Comment: Please Edit your post with the extra info

Comment: And your definition for intlist_t

Comment: I've added more information to show what is done at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your code:

```
void intlist_removeall(intlist_t *list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);
    free(list);
}
```

Now, ask yourself, "what changes did I make to the `intlist` object?"

From where I sit, assuming you are using the standard `assert` and the standard `free` (as opposed to some custom functions you may have written), you haven't done anything.

Did you update the size? No.

Did you update the capacity? No.

Did you reset the individual elements to some known starting value like 0? No.

The only thing you did (since `assert` will be #ifdef'ed out depending on your compiler switches) is to call `free(list)` which tells the *memory allocation subsystem* that you are done using that particular block.

If you are in a multithreaded environment, it's possible that some other thread might write to your list data structure between your call to `free` and your return from `intlist_removeall`. Otherwise, you have just updated the allocation tracking data, and created a dangling pointer into memory that will likely be re-used sometime later, when it can cause your program to crash.

Ask yourself this: If you want to "record" that an element has been removed, what should you do?

I suspect you will update the size element, and maybe move/copy all the "after" elements forward to cover the gap.

You should do a similar thing in the case of `removeall`, except that it's a little easier since you know the size is going down to zero, and there won't be any left over elements.

Also, what is `removeall` compared to `destroy`? Why are you freeing the structure? In Python, a list of length zero is still a list - it's not `None` or `undef` or anything.

```
intlist_t * list1 = NULL;
intlist_t * list2 = intlist_construct(10);
```

What's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `remove_all`, and `free(list);` you are freeing your pointer to the list. This does not achieve what you want you to do, and you also haven't freed `list->elems*`, which will give you a run time error later. 
You ought to code up what you expect your data structure to behave like. What you want is possible without freeing any memory at all.

You can simply work with your size variable.